# Why the jumbotron class is not working in bootstrap 5 version?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In the bootstrap 5 version, the jumbotron class is not working.
what do you think?
if anyone knows so please help out me.
I am really confused.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="jumbotron">Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

> The jumbotron component is removed in favor of utility classes like
> `.bg-light` for the background color and `.p-*` classes to control
> padding.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#jumbotron

Answer (score 3):

The Jumbotron class has been removed in bootstrap 5. If you still want it, use Bootstrap 4, replace your `h1` tag with `div` and put the "Hello, World" in a nested `h1`. This should work:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/